# How do you store a function on an object? Powershell

Tags: javascript, powershell

trying to recreate this dynamic switch javascript code for use in powershell, but can't figure out how to store the function on the object in order to work as a switch statement.

```
const customSwitch = [
  {
    condition: "case1",
    fn() {
      console.log("case1 ran");
    },
  },
  {
    condition: "canBeChangedAnytime",
    fn() {
      /* Do stuff if case2 */
    },
  },
];

// use the switch
for (const { condition, fn } of customSwitch) {
  if (myValue === condition) {
    fn();
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: This code is working fine what is the problem you are facing right now?

Comment: I commend to your attention [Microsoft Learning on Scriptblocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2).

Comment: @ShoaibAmin i know the code works but it's written in javascript and not powershell,

Comment: @JeffZeitlin , maybe I'm mistaken or if it's just because i'm new to ps but I am not seeing how ScriptBlocks can help here after watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WP_Olf8GH_g, can you elaborate?